# Using Apple Script to Select Safari Dropdowns with *Browser Event*

Tags: javascript, safari, applescript

I am running an apple script to input and select fields on an online web form using Safari browser.
The web form has dropdowns, which once selected, triggers changes in subsequent fields.

For example, two dropdowns: `Field 1` `Field 2`

`Field 1` is a required selection, and `Field 2` is only enabled after the user selects `Field 1`.

If I use applescript to enter a value for `Field 1`, the value is selected.

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementById('"Field_1"').value ='"theValue"';" in document 1
```

However, the browser does not register this selection, and `Field 2` remains disabled.  The change of value of `Field 1` is displayed, but the page behaves as if this selection has not been made.

Is there anyway for me to trigger a browser event to register that the `Field 1` selection has been made?

Thanks

Comment: Try to enable the second dropdown, like this --> `document.getElementById("Field_2").disabled = false;`

Comment: Thanks, that's a step in the right direction.  The dropdown becomes enabled but the selections are not populated.  The selection of Field 1 also triggers generating the selections available for Field 2.
So right now, the field is enabled, but it's blank.

Comment: if the dropdown have an attribute which call a function, like this --> `<select id='Field_1' name='Field_1'  onchange="myFunction(this.value);">` , use a command to trigger the **onchange**, like this  `do JavaScript "document.getElementById('Field_1').onchange()" in document 1`

Comment: Thanks, took some tweaks but managed to implement it with either option below:

**Option 1)** `do JavaScript "document.getElementById('"Field_1"').value ='"theValue"'; $('#Field_1').change();" in document 1`, or **Option 2)** `$('#Field_1 option[value=theValue]').prop('selected', true).change()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the app you're using also load jQuery? If so, it makes this task a lot easier. Here's how you'd modify your script to use jQuery:

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementById('"Field_1"').value ='"theValue"'; $('#"Field_1"').change();" in document 1
```